flying-saucer-pdf missing type DocumentException
I am trying to use flying-saucer-pdf to transform HTML to Pdf.
While following multiple tutorials: (which might be copied form each other...)

https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-generate-pdf
https://tuhrig.de/generating-pdfs-with-java-flying-saucer-and-thymeleaf/
https://www.baeldung.com/java-html-to-pdf (flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf is now flying-saucer-pdf)
Snippets here on StackOverflow

I always get the same error:
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method createPDF(OutputStream) from the type ITextRenderer refers to the missing type DocumentException


It didn't compile till I added "import org.xhtmlrenderer.*;", which made the error wait till execution...
I understand that I either need the dependency for that class, which seems to be com.lowagie.text.DocumentException (surce:doc). I  couldn't find out how to get that source, and it seems strange because the tutorials don't use it.
My pom.xml is set up just as in these tutorials:
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
    <version>9.5.1</version><!-- also with 9.94-->
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.2</version>
</dependency>

module-info:
    requires org.jsoup;
    requires flying.saucer.pdf;
    requires flying.saucer.core;

my relevant code:
Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlString, "UTF-8");
                document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
            
                try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("outputPDF.pdf")) {
                    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
                    SharedContext sharedContext = renderer.getSharedContext();
                    sharedContext.setPrint(true);
                    sharedContext.setInteractive(false);
                    renderer.setDocumentFromString(document.html());
                    renderer.layout();
                    renderer.createPDF(outputStream); //<--- Problem here
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

How do I fix this? (or how do I create a pdf from (x)html/css/images)?
EDIT: I got it to work - turns out it works when removing the module-info.java file entirely. Why? I got no clue, can somebody tell me?

Can you try adding a requires statement for itext to the module-info.java?

I tried several variations, but the module itext (com.itext, com.itextpdf) could not be found (with, or without mvn dependancy com.itextpdf).

So. I cloned the tutorial, got the part I need  to work, put that in a different project, removed unnecessary dependencies /etc. It still works. When I copy that to my project (exactly) it doesn't work.
Since the tutorial didn't have a module-info.java, i tried compiling (maven) without that file, and now everything still works? How did that happen?
